# How to Filter by Post Arguments in ListView

Tags: django

I am trying to create a form in my ListView which POSTs to the ListView and filters by the POSTed attributes.

This is in a Django 2.1 project.

I have tried passing both self and request argunments to the post function but I am receiving the Exception below
e.g.

`def post(self, request):`

results in a TypeError exception:

`post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

If I try to solve the error by removing one of the parameters so that only self is passed to the post() `def post(self)` function I receive the following TypeError exception:

`post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Despite the fact that only self has been passed. I have tried only passing request and that results in the same thing.

Lots of examples online show
`def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

This results in the obvious exceptions of:
`too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Removing all arguments results in a TypeError:
`post() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

class thing_dashboard(ListView):
    ''' All Orders processed '''

```
template_name = 'thing/orders_dashboard.html'
paginate_by = 25 

def post(self, request):
    queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('-ordered_date')
    rejected = self.request.POST.get('rejected')
    if rejected == 'False':
        queryset = Order.objects.filter(state='rejected')
        return queryset
    return queryset

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('-ordered_date')
    return queryset
```

I am expecting to be able to like in a simple function based view to refer to self.request.POST.get() and then handle the logic to return the filtered queryset I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the post method, then try it:

```
template_name = 'thing/orders_dashboard.html'
paginate_by = 25 

def get_queryset(self):
    rejected = self.request.POST.get('rejected') or None
    if rejected:
        return Order.objects.filter(state='rejected').order_by('-ordered_date')
    return Order.objects.all().order_by('-ordered_date')
```

Comment: I have done this and this results in a 405 which I believe is caused by the ListView not having a method to process POST requests.  I have tried converting the form to a GET and it works but it doesn't really provide me with an answer for how to do this as a POST request.